# Need help for installing hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, cygwin, classpath

I am new to Hadoop and trying to install it on my windows 7 (x64) PC using cygwin.
I followed this tutorial to install http://alans.se/blog/2010/hadoop-hbase-cygwin-windows-7-x64/#software

Everything goes correct before this step -

```
Only Hadoop 0.21.0: Next, one line has to be added to the hadoop-config.sh file in hadoop-0.21.-0/bin

    CLASSPATH=`cygpath -wp "$CLASSPATH"`

Add this line before the line containing

    JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=''
```

Does this line 
    CLASSPATH=`cygpath -wp "$CLASSPATH"` need to be copied as it is?

Coz when I am trying to run command below.

```
    $ bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

I am getting such error from cygwin

```
/usr/local/hadoop-0.21.0/bin/hadoop-config.sh: line 15: $'\r': command not found
/usr/local/hadoop-0.21.0/bin/hadoop-config.sh: line 19: $'\r': command not found
/usr/local/hadoop-0.21.0/bin/hadoop-config.sh: line 21: $'\r': command not found
/usr/local/hadoop-0.21.0/bin/hadoop-config.sh: line 75: syntax error near unexpected token `$'in\r''
'usr/local/hadoop-0.21.0/bin/hadoop-config.sh: line 75: `case "`uname`" in 
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

HDFS not found.
```

can anyone explain what is going wrong?

Comment: Did you try using the recommended command? What's your `$CLASSPATH`?

Comment: @DaveNewton: The tutorial says something like this...

The reason for this is that in order for the CLASSPATH to be build with all the Hadoop jars (line ~120 to ~200) the path needs to be in the Cygwin format (/cygdrive/c/cygwin/usr/local/hadoop…), however in order for Java use the classpath, it needs to be in the Windows format (c:\cygwin\usr\local\hadoop..). The line transforms the Cygwin built classpath to one that is understood by Windows.

what does this mean??

Answer (score 0):

you are using a deprecated command. For a list of hadoop commands, enter hadoop on your console. I believe the command is hadoop namenode -format

Comment: @DaveNewton: thats where i am confused...
in this line CLASSPATH=cygpath -wp "$CLASSPATH"
am I supposed to write the path of the hadoop folder in windows by replacing $CLASSPATH and path of hadoop in cygwin by replacing cygpath ??

Answer (score 0):

I also got these errors using cygwin 1.7:

> /usr/local/hadoop-0.21.0/bin/hadoop-config.sh: line 15: $'\r': command
>   not found

It appears that these files are not in DOS CR/LF format instead of the expected UNIX format.

You can confirm this with a text editor like Notepad++.  In the lower right hand part of the window, it can say Dos\Windows (very likely what you would see) or UNIX.

To work around these errors, in a cygwin window I used the command dos2unix *.sh in the bin folder and other folders (conf, etc...) as needed.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Convert the config.sh file or any  config file needed in d build to unix format with dos2unix *filename* (shell command). It seems the files changes to DOS format by default. Better convert every file in d folder to unix with (dos2unix ./*) shell command.

Answer (score 0):

The error with Cygwin seems to be a known error with npm script. You can use the work around mentioned here,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22436199/2390020