# How add commands to cygwin - npm

Tags: windows, path, environment-variables, cygwin

I use cygwin on windows 8.1 to have an Unix shell. But I cannot run commands such as npm from it.

What should I do to do it? Add some kind of env var to cygwin? Why it doesn't use windows PATH?

Edit:
Actually I think that I misunderstood the problem here. It looks like npm is found by cygwin but it cannot be used. For instance I can use git from cygwin without any trouble.

```
$ npm
/cygdrive/d/Logiciels installés/nodejs/npm: line 2: $'\r' : command not found
/cygdrive/d/Logiciels installés/nodejs/npm: line 4: $'\r' : command not found
/cygdrive/d/Logiciels installés/nodejs/npm: line 5: Syntax error around « $'in\r' »
'cygdrive/d/Logiciels installés/nodejs/npm: line 5: `case `uname` in
```

So, it looks actually more like a npm issue.

Comment: I would not -personally- recommend using Cygwin anymore. I now use Babun, which is an enhanced Cygwin + Zsh for windows! http://babun.github.io/

Comment: As you can see from the error message, `npm` (which must be a script in some shell language) contains carriage returns. You can verify this with the hex editor of your choice (or with `xxd`) and remove them with `dos2unix`. However I wondered **how** you had installed `npm` that you ended up with these weird line endings.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with the npm script as mentioned here, https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5912

Assuming you have installed nodejs in the default location you can run the following dos2unix command and fix the error.

> dos2unix c:/Program\ Files/nodejs/npm

This fixed my problems with the npm script.

Comment: Didn't know about dos2unix before! That helped me a ton - thanks!

Comment: On Windows you can find dos2unix.exe here with a few other soft (unix2dos, ..) http://sourceforge.net/projects/dos2unix/?source=typ_redirect
Just put the extracted folder somewhere in C:\ and add the path to the PATH environment variable.

Comment: did not work for me though. any suggestions? would be really appreciated

Comment: There is no 'sudo' in cygwin!

Comment: Furthermore, what works in linux, except that it displays nothing but "Loading..." in the browser, crashes on npm start in either cygwin or DOS!  So much for any semblance/pretense of portability!

Comment: Only in /cygdrive/c/Share/node_modules_cygwin: @ngtools
(i.e., no such buggy code in Linux!)

Answer (score 6):

### How to make cygwin work with npm command

1. install http://nodejs.org/#download
2. download http://nodejs.org/dist/npm/
3. extract npm.zip into node.exe
4. run cygwin terminal again

That is it!

Comment: This worked for me just by installing node for Windows and then restarting cygwin shell. ty!

Comment: @Abudayah how did you do step one? just extracting the folder?

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix the npm script to work even with dos encoding, i submitted a [patch.](https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/5180)